# How to take full advantage of Dual monitor setup in terms of productivity?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, productivity

What are useful, apps, tricks, techniques?

for Windows XP 32 bit dual-monitor setup.

*Please provide portable and freeware only*

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

[Winsplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) is great for moving windows around by using keyboard shortcuts.
It also offers functions to position windows on just one screen which also works for single but big monitors.

Comment: @mxp - +1 good apps

Answer (score 2):

Consider the upgrade to Windows 7 which has more builtin support, but if that isn't an option, there's a good list of techniques and applications [here](http://lifehacker.com/317479/make-the-most-of-your-dual-monitors)

Answer (score 1):

I find it very useful to keep my main work on the primary monitor (19" widescreen) and all the preipheral stuff (e.g. mail, webbrowser, musicplayer) on my second monitor. It keeps your attention to your work, but you can still view in one glance if there is something that desires your attention.

AAlso, since I am a Delphi programmer, I keep my code on the primary monitor and all dbugging windows on the secondary. This keeps my area in which to view code large and has the added advantage that during debugging I can see both the debugging windows as well as the application I am working on.

One more tip, UltraMon. It's not free but, offers a lot of handy features:

- Split Wallpapers
- Extra taskbar on second monitor
- Quick and scaled moving of windows between monitors (even when full-screen).

Free alternatives: DisplayFusion and Multimon.

Comment: The free version of Display Fusion is very limited.  None of the 2nd monitor taskbar apps fully support win7 yet.  Display Fusion and Task Se7en current come closest depending on what features you want.  DF is best if your preferred configuration is similar to that of prior versions of windows with each app in a seperate taskbar item with text showing.  If you like all your windows grouped into a single text-free icon (win7 default) Task Se7en is what you want.  AFAIK noone has a bar that supports both modes.

Comment: +1 for not only providing links, but explaining how do you use your configuration as a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Have at least one monitor sideways ("portrait" as opposed to "landscape"). Editing source code and documents on a sideways monitor gives you more of an overview of your work.

Comment: pls explain more what r u saying

Comment: @Jitendra; Rotate your monitor 90 degrees so you have more vertical space than horizontal.

Comment: but how to rotate? it has stand at bottom

Comment: @Jitendra vyas:  IT depends on the monitor.  The cheapest ones don't have rotating stands but at normal sizes most do allow you to rotate the screen 90* in one direction.  With really large (eg >24") monitors rotation tends to disappear from midrange monitors and only be supported by high end ones.

Comment: My monitors don't have rotatable stands... I have improvised a stand with cardboard and cellotape! It looks horrid but makes my work so much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to add a comment so I'm adding it as a question..

@Dan Neely - Just for the record, Task Se7en has supported Image only and Image/Text buttons for quite some time now. DisplayFusion does as well but, requires itself to restart its taskbar when switching from one button mode to the other while Task Se7en does not and will animate the switch without any kind of restart.